# Using image typed input with AJAX/JQuery/PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am making a rock, paper, scissors game using AJAX, which is how I am learning JQuery, and I think it is almost all there. But, I can't get my buttons to work correctly. I am using `<input type="image" ... >` for my input source, and there will be three of these clickable pictures. I made a separate JS file to try and get the buttons to trigger an alert, and I don't know why they are not working. I feel like I have been looking at the code too long to see the bug, so I could use your fresh eyes, as well as your experience in the languages. Thanks!

play.php:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include "./header.php";
    include "logic/ajax.php";
?>

<!Doctype html>
    <head>
        <title>Play</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/play.css">
        <script src="logic/buttonTest.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <p>
    <h6>Session Wins: <label for="s-wins"> <input id="score-wins" type="text"> </label> </h6>

    <h6>Session Losses: <label for="s-losses"> <input id="score-losses" type="text"> </label> </h6>

    <h6>Total Wins: <label for="t-wins"> <input id="total-wins" type="text"> </label> </h6>

    <h6>Total Losses: <label for="t-losses"> <input id="total-losses" type="text"> </label> </h6>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <form id="rock">
                    <input id="rock" type="image" src="assets/rock.png" alt="ROCK">
                </form>
            </td>

            <td>
                <form id="paper">
                    <input id="paper" type="image" src="assets/paper.png" alt="PAPER">
                </form>
            </td>

            <td>
                <form id="scissors">
                    <input id="scissors" type="image" src="assets/scissors.png" alt="SCISSORS">
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </body>

<?php include "./footer.php"; ?>
```

buttonTest.js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#rock").on('click', function(){
        alert("You Clicked Rock");
    });

    $("#paper").click(function(){
        alert("You Clicked Paper");
    });

    $("#scissors").click(function(){
        alert("You Clicked Scissors");
    });
});
```

Comment: You have a bunch of duplicate IDs (form and input pairs), and I wouldn't be surprised if that's confusing jQuery.

Comment: I started with the ID only on the FORM, then I tried it on the INPUT. Then I tried it on both, and that's how we got here.

Answer (score 0):

the default behaviour of of `input` with `type="image"` is to follow the `src` attribute ,so you need to disable the default  behaviour in all your handlers .

```
  $("#rock").on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("You Clicked Rock");
    });
```

do the same for all other click handlers

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple errors in your code:

1. You're loading the js files before the `<body>` is even rendered, you should place them right before the closing `</body>` tag.
2. You should invert the order of your `<script>` tags, firstly you should load jquery, then your script that uses it.
3. You should avoid using the same id on multiple elements cause it may cause problems.
4. If your form is not intended to submit info but just to contain an input just switch them to `<div>`